# Python3 logging: Pass LogRecord to function

Tags: python-3.x, logging

With the `logging` module of python3 I am logging to a file like this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='log')
logging.info('123')
```

Now everytime a logging event occurs, i want a function to be called as well with the LogRecord as an argument.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `logging.Filter` object that reviews the `LogRecord` and decides whether or not it should be logged. In this code you could also perform other logic: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects.